# Searching large (6 million) rows MySQL with stored queries?

Tags: mysql, highcharts

I have a database with roughly 6 million entries - and will grow - where I'm running queries to return for a HighCharts charting functionality. I need to read longitudinally over years, so I'm running queries like this:

```
foreach($states as $state_id) { //php code
    SELECT  //mysql psuedocode
    sum(case when mydatabase.Year = '2003' then 1 else 0 end) Year_2003,
    sum(case when mydatabase.Year = '2004' then 1 else 0 end) Year_2004,
    sum(case when mydatabase.Year = '2005' then 1 else 0 end) Year_2005,
    sum(case when mydatabase.Year = '2006' then 1 else 0 end) Year_2006,
    sum(case when mydatabase.Year = '2007' then 1 else 0 end) Year_2007,
    sum(case when mydatabase.Year = '$more_years' then 1 else 0 end) Year_$whatever_year,
    FROM mytable
    WHERE  State='$state_id' 
    AND  Sex IN (0,1)  
    AND  Age_segment IN (5,4,3,2,1)
    AND "other_filters IN (etc, etc, etc)
 } //end php code
```

But for various state at once... So returning lets say 5 states, each with the above statement but a state ID is substituted.  Meanwhile the years can be any number of years, the Sex (male/female/other) and Age segment and other modifiers keep changing based on filters.  The queries are long (at minimum 30-40seconds) a piece. So a thought I had - unless I'm totally doing it wrong - is to actually store the above query in a second table with the results, and first check that "meta query" and see if it was "cached" and then return the results without reading the db (which won't be updated very often).

Is this a good method or are there potential problems I'm not seeing?

EDIT: changed to table, not db (duh).

Table structure is:

```
id | Year | Sex | Age_segment | Another_filter | Etc
```

Nothing more complicated than that and no joining anything else. There are keys on id, Year, Sex, and Age_segment right now.

Comment: It's not easy to answer clearly without knowing what your `mydatabase` fact table actually looks like. Please [edit] your question to show the definition of that table.

Comment: Forget about the pivoting stuff. Just return an ordered array of years and counts, and handle all the display stuff in the presentation layer.

Comment: @Strawberry you mean GROUP BY or how do you mean years & counts?

Comment: Not knowing your data, I would aggregate your data for all states and insert it into an aggregate table. Then, you could do a simple select to fetch the data.

Comment: Thank you Doug. Can you point me to a resource on what you're thinking of as aggregation? I'm imagining it might be something like I was thinking as well but don't have the vocab or resource to elaborate.

Comment: To be clear Doug, because people can filter by state, year, sex, etc that means because I have 15 years, 50 states, 2 possible Sex values, etc, it seems to me I'm looking at an aggregate table of all possibilities, eg over half a million values (15 * 50 * 2 * xx). Again, I hope I'm not misunderstanding...

Comment: There are different ways to do it, but the point point of an aggregate is to have all data in a single row. So, I would sum every value per state, then use a group by year, selecting max(state) with a case statement for each state. This would put every state in a single data row with a 100 columns. Or, you could calculate everything down to the month, then sum for year. The goal is to reduce the amount of rows you calculate on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper indexing is what is needed to speed up the query. Start by doing an "EXPLAIN" on the query and post the results here.

I would suggest the following to start off. This way avoids the for loop and returns the data in 1 query. Not knowing the number of rows and cardinality of each column I suggest a composite index on State and Year.

```
SELECT mytable.State,mytable.Year,count(*)
FROM mytable
AND  Sex IN (0,1)  
AND  Age_segment IN (5,4,3,2,1)
AND "other_filters IN (etc, etc, etc)
GROUP BY mytable.State,mytable.Year
```

The above query can be further optimised by checking the cardinality of some of the columns. Run the following to get the cardinality:

```
SELECT Age_segment FROM mytable GROUP BY Age_segment;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code...

```
SELECT Year
     , COUNT(*) total
  FROM my_its_not_a_database_its_a_table 
 WHERE State = $state_id
   AND Sex IN (0,1)  
   AND  Age_segment IN (5,4,3,2,1)
 GROUP
    BY Year;
```

Comment: This means I'm running 5 queries (say, for each State) from the frontend. Over that much data (and this is for one chart on a page of many, with AJAX) its still slow. Unless I'm misundersting.

Comment: This is one query. If you want to return data from several states, include the state column in the SELECT (and the GROUP BY), and remove it from the WHERE clause. Similarly for sex and age.